# Evaporation of zinc oxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, thermodynamics, transition-metals, evaporation

My question involves the evaporation of silicate material (e.g., rocks, minerals, geologic material), specifically I am trying to work the number of electrons (*n*) that are involved in the evaporation reactions described by [Sossi et al. (2019)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0016703719303606) and [Sossi and Fegley (2018)](https://pubs.geoscienceworld.org/msa/rimg/article-abstract/84/1/393/566363/Thermodynamics-of-Element-Volatility-and-its?redirectedFrom=fulltext).

As an example, I will discuss the evaporation of zinc oxide (ZnO), which is shown in multiple sources (see footnotes) as:

[image]

Sossi et al. (2019) state that this reaction involves two electrons (*n*=+2), however they do not indicate how they came to this value, so I have been trying to work it out myself. I should also note that they describe these reactions as **producing a metal bearing gas**.

I have two lines of thinking for determining *n* for this reaction:

***First line of reasoning***

ZnO(l) has two components with charges Zn = +2 and O = -2

Zn(g) evaporates as a metal, so the charge is Zn = 0

and

1/2O2 is just oxygen gas with charge 1/2O2 = 0.5*(-2*2) = -2

This line of reasoning implies that there was a change in the charge on Zn of -2. In other words, two electrons were lost, so two electrons were involved in the reaction. It involves the production of gaseous zinc metal, which fits nicely into the description of a metal bearing gas, at least in my mind. **However, this leaves the reaction unbalanced because the products have a -2 charge, which leads me to my second line of reasoning.**

***Second line of reasoning***

ZnO(l) his a stable compound, so ZnO = 0 charge

Zn(g) evaporates as a cation, so the charge is Zn = +2

and

1/2O2 is just oxygen gas with charge 1/2O2 = 0.5*(-2*2) = -2

Now the reaction is charge balanced, **but I am not clear on how two electrons were involved in this case, unless I can consider the two electrons that "went with" Zn after the evaporation of ZnO** as the two electrons that are involved in the reaction. However, I don't know if Zn++(g) counts as a metal bearing gas, which the authors say is present.

I have been tying myself in knots trying to work this out, so any guidance in the right direction would be helpful.

*Footnotes*

Other sources that discuss the evaporation of ZnO include [Anthrop and Searcy (1964)](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/j100790a052?casa_token=1KAaaACIL_kAAAAA:iagmpmVhquDMTO8Imm7jQpA4PblgJYkPoGqc6wni_s26NBerBCdIwkjxMbX-sfgcE51FpaU5rU49e0PURw) and [Kodera et al. (1968)](https://www.journal.csj.jp/doi/abs/10.1246/bcsj.41.1039)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your following sentence is wrong (I copy it in italics without change)

*1/2O2 is just oxygen gas with charge 1/2O2 = 0.5*(-2*2) = -2*

No! There is no charge $-2$ on the oxygen atom in the molecule $\ce{O2}$, and no charge at all in the molecule $\ce{O2}$ There is a charge $-2$ on the oxygen atom in the initial oxide $\ce{ZnO}$. But during the decomposition of $\ce{ZnO}$, the two electrons available on the Oxygen ion are transferred to the zinc ion $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ which becomes a non-charged atom $\ce{Zn}$.

Comment: Thank you for catching that mistake! That means that Zn is evaporating as Zn metal (Zn+0), correct?

Comment: Boiling point of Zn is 907°C, deep below the melting point 1974°C of ZnO,  at which it is said being already decomposing.

Comment: @Poutnik I understand what you're saying, but I don't follow why that's relevant. Are you saying that my comment is incorrect?

Comment: @eyemarrs It is just a side info.

Comment: Yes, Zn is evaporating as Zn metal, mixed with neutral oxygen atoms. But when this gas is cooled down, it synthesizes back zinc oxide.